# Jupyter Notebook not displaying correctly after reinstall

Tags: jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I'm using Jupyter Notebook through Anaconda. It was working fine until I uninstalled and reinstalled it. Now when I create a new notebook, the cells do not have the same coloring, there is no number to the left, and there is no output when I run a cell. Did I miss something when I reinstalled it?

I've also reinstalled Anaconda.

Comment: Depending on how old your original installation was vs the new one, I wonder if you have old things around interferring? It is always best to clean things out entirely before you do a fresh install of there Anaconda Distribution. You should look around for resources on that. Some of what I have [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/jupyter-cant-import-tensorflow/24330/12?u=fomightez) may expand on this.